# What's the equivalent of the resistance for steady stokes flow? Inverse of the viscosity tensor?

Tags: electrical-resistance, tensor-calculus, viscosity, navier-stokes, transport-phenomena

it is well known that we describe electrical propagation in a conductor using the conductivity matrix $A$, through the following laplace equation:

$$div(A(x) \nabla u(x))=f(x)$$
where $u$ is the electric potential (in $\mathbb{R}$) and $A$ is the *conductivity matrix*. A(x) describes the local conductivity in the point $x$.

We can define the *resistance matrix* which is $B=A^{-1}$.

### Question

I would like to know if is possible to define the same thing to study a steady incompressible stokes flow:

$$2 div( \mu(x) D(u)(x))+\nabla p(x)=f(x), \quad div(u(x))=0$$
where $u$ is the fluid velocity (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), $D(u)=\frac{\nabla u + \nabla u^t}{2}$ is it's symetric gradient, $f$ is a source term and $p$ is the pression in the fluid. Here, $\mu(x)$ is called the **viscosity tensor** and it is basically an application from $3 \times 3$ matrixes toward $3 \times 3$ matrixes, **it plays the same role as the conductivity matrix in the scalar electrical problem above**.

I was wondering if there exists an equivalent to the resistance matrix for this problem, however I am unfamiliar with the definition of the inverse of a tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transport coefficients for electrical transport are also tensors. So, it's not just a "resistance matrix", it's a [resistance tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Tensor_resistivity), and its inverse is the conductivity tensor.

In general, all [transport coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_coefficient) are tensors, and you can represent them either as conductivities or resistivities. E.g. thermal conductivity and thermal resistivity for heat transport.

I have no experience with the viscosity tensor, but it [seems to be a transport coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_phenomena#Commonalities_among_phenomena), so I don't see why it would be any different. If the viscosity tensor can be represented as a 3x3 matrix, you should be able to invert it to find the equivalent resistivity matrix, which will be a matrix representation of the resistivity tensor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, the viscosity tensor is indeed a transport coefficient ( I'm not really sure what it transports though). In my case, the tensor is a linear map from symetric matrixes to symetric matrixes so I can represent it as a $6 \times 6$ matrix and probably invert it.

Comment: @Velobos it is the liquid that is transported, whereas the transport coefficients characterize the strength of the flow in response to the external force (e.g., the strength of electric current in response to applied bias/electric field).